# websocket behind reverse proxy alias

Tags: websocket, socket.io, alias

I installed a nodeJS server behind a reverse proxy with an alias.
Basically i'd like to reach my nodeJS server on : http://myapp.domain.intra/chat

but it seems that when, on the client, i do : var socket = io("http://myapp.domain.intra/chat",...)
the '/chat' is truncated and the connection tries to connect on the domain only : 'myapp.domain.intra', which does not work.

I do understand that basically the /chat is interpreted as a scope but how can I force socket IO take the /chat in account as the connection url?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found it. It's pretty easy.

I needed to set the path option like so :

var socket = io.connect("http://myapp.domain.intra",{path:'/chat/socket.io'});